# Using XSLT to copy part of an XML as HTML

Tags: xslt

I'm using an XSL document to format an XML into HTML.
Part of the XML is an HTML fragment. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="formatter.xsl"?>
<root>
    <some-node>text</some-node>
    <another-node>text</another-node>
    <html-container>
        <p>This is an HTML with <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">links</a> and <i>other stuff</i>.</p>
        <p>And on and on it goes...</p>
    </html-container>
</root>
```

My XSL does lots of manipulations on the XML, but the part inside `<html-container>` needs to be copied to the new XML as is - all HTML nodes and attributes.

I've tried using this template:

```
<xsl:template match="html-container/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But this copies just the child nodes, no other descendants:

```
<p>This is an HTML with links and other stuff.</p>
<p>And on and on it goes...</p>
```

I've also tried:

```
<xsl:template match="html-container//*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But then the attributes are copied as text:

```
<p>This is an HTML with <a>http://www.google.com_blanklinks</a> and <i>other stuff</i>.</p>
<p>And on and on it goes...</p>
```

Obviously I'm missing something. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `xsl:apply-templates`, then you should usually have templates that match the nodes and attributes you select. The one you tried, that matched `html-container//*` will only match elements, but you also need to match attributes as well.

```
<xsl:template match="html-container//*|html-container//@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Note, this is very much like the XSLT identity template, which would look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This would match elements outside `html-container`, which may or may not affect your current XSLT.

Alternatively, if the descendants of `html-container` need to be copies as-is, without any changes, just use `xsl:copy-of` instead

```
<xsl:template match="html-container/*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Both options work - with `xsl:apply-templates` and with `xsl:copy-of`.
Many thanks!